# Serialize Friend class members

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization

I have a class with friend fields and properties.
I want to serialize the hole class using

```
Dim Ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim MyString As String = Ser.Serialize(MyClass)
```

Is that possible?

I can iterate the class using system.reflection and setting the flag to NonPublic. Is it possible to do something similar when using system.web.script.Serialization?

Tried to play with **JSON.Net** but it didn't get me anywhere either, could only serialize public members :-(

UPDATE:

I found a work-around using **JSON.net** by adding the attribute " **JsonPropertyAttribute**" to the non-public members:

```
Class MyClass
     <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute>
     Friend myStr as string
End Class
```

It's not optimal but must do for now...

Comment: A DataContract serializer like DataContractJsonSerializer should allow it.  I am not certain but I think there is a way to do it with JSON.NET too.

Comment: Tried to look into DataContractJsonSerializer but couldn't figure out how to use it.....but thanks for the hint.